Remove Item from cart in ASP.NET in stepForm
this is my method for add and remove Items from session :
   public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(int chefFoodId, bool stayInCartPage = false)
   {
       var item = await _orderService.GetItemByChefFoodId(chefFoodId);
       if (item != null)
       {
           _siteService.SaveInSession(item);
       }

       // Save returnUrl in session
       var returnUrl = stayInCartPage ? "/UserPanel/ShowCart" : "/";
       HttpContext.Session.SetString("returnUrl", returnUrl);

       // Check value in Both View: FoodMenu & ShowCart
       if (stayInCartPage)
       {
           return RedirectToAction("ShowCart", "Home", new { area = "UserPanel" });
       }
       else
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
       }
   }



   public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveFromCart(int chefFoodId)
   {
       var item = await _orderService.GetItemByChefFoodId(chefFoodId);
       if (item != null)
       {
           _siteService.RemoveFromSession(item);
       }

       return RedirectToAction("ShowCart");
   }
  

My cart View is a step form that have some internal Form , and first form have an Id for control of StepForm:
 <form action="#" id="step-form-horizontal" class=" ">
...

in part of + , - for add and remove item I have these forms:
      <td class="col-3">
          <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RemoveFromCart" method="post" class="d-inline">
                      <input type="hidden" name="chefFoodId" value="@item.ChefFoodId" />
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">-</button>
                          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                  </form>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control text-center quantity-input" value="@item.Quantity" readonly data-id="@item.ChefFoodId">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                  <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddToCart" method="post" class="d-inline">
                      <input type="hidden" name="chefFoodId" value="@item.ChefFoodId" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="stayInCartPage" value="true" />
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">+</button>
                          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </td>

but just addTocart work and remove does not work, when I change main form to section , both of methods work
But I Can not change this part to section like:
<Section action="#" id="step-form-horizontal" class=" ">
If I change to section , how ever removefromCart method will be work , but form does not work.
How do I do to have both , stem form work correct , and Remove method work correct

Hi @Maryam12 forex,  From your description, it seems you need implement remove/add the item in the cart and also you can post all the item in cart to backend,right? If so, it will contain a main form in the view and contains several nested forms inside this form. You need know that nested forms are invalid html and not supported.  To achieve your requirement, you could use Section to make remove/add work, then use ajax to make the main form submit work. For better help, more code of you razor view and action design would be helpful.

I've just share a simple demo for how to post the value you want to backend with button click. Due to you do not share the whole razor view code, if any problems, pls share with your whole code. Thanks.

Nested forms are invalid html and not supported. To achieve your requirement,you could remove the nested form and set asp-route-xxx in the button to send the value you want(e.g asp-route-chefFoodId="@item.ChefFoodId", asp-route-stayInCartPage="true"), pls follow the code below:
@model CartModel
<form asp-action="YourAction" method="YourMethod">
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-3">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3 input-group-sm">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <button asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RemoveFromCart" asp-route-chefFoodId="@item.ChefFoodId" method="post" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">-</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center quantity-input" value="@item.Quantity" readonly data-id="@item.ChefFoodId">
                        <div class="input-group-append">                            
                             <button asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-chefFoodId="@item.ChefFoodId" asp-route-stayInCartPage="true" method="post" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">+</button>                             
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="post" />
</form>

